# How can I get `gpg` to sign with certain key again (end of file error)

Tags: digital-signature, key-management, gnupg

Disclaimer: This is a cross-post after [I initially was looking for help on the Gentoo forums](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1128975.html) since I suspected some major update of my Gentoo system to be the reason behind my problem.
However, since then I found that my GnuPG setup is working except for with that one specific key, plus I did not get any useful feedback over there (zero feedback after two weeks by now).

My issue surfaced after a complicated system update that involved switching out LibreSSL for OpenSLL and updating GnuPG from 2.2.20-r1 to 2.2.25, Git complained that it could not sign my commits anymore.

To rule out Git being the culprit, I tried signing some text with my Git signing key directly via `gpg`:

```
gpg --clearsign <<< test
```

On the first run this runs `pinentry` to prompt me for the key's passphrase, which seems to works properly: `pinentry` can tell when I give a wrong passphrase (offering me another try) and closes successfully if I give the correct one. Also passing that information to `gpg` appears to be working just fine: Once I have 'unlocked' the key by entering the correct passphrase into the `pinentry` prompt, I can re-run the `gpg` command without being prompted for the passphrase again.

However, instead of signing the message with the unlocked key, `gpg` fails with an 'end of file' error. All I could find online regarding such an error was [this short note in the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Agent_complains_end_of_file) hinting at issues between `pinentry` and `dbus`. Thus, my initial suspicion of a general system setup issue caused by the update.
But in the meantime I found that everything is working just fine, as long as I use a newly generated key. In both cases, the key in question is an ed25519 sign-only key with identical preferences. With the new key, I do not get any error, but with the key I actually want to sign with, I keep getting the 'end of file' error.

This made me think there could be an unrelated issue with the key (or some other file in my user's `~/.gnupg/` directory) that broke that particular key. Luckily, I happened to have a copy of that keypair on another user's keyring on that same machine. So I could put that to a test by switching user (and thus keyrings and in in turn key and user-specific configuration files) while staying on the same system (and thus using the same binaries). It turnd out that I could reproduce that exact behaviour: My Git signing key fails with 'end of file' but a newly generated key with the same properties works just fine.

Is there anything I can do to safe that signing key? Obviously I could just switch keys but the new one won't have the same trust associated as the existing one. Also, what if something like this happens to my main signing key, used to sign the keys I use for encryption and such? My workflow relies too much on GnuPG working as intended to just shrug and work around this without getting to the bottom of this unexpected issue.

So what is a good procedure to troubleshoot an 'end of file' error during GnuPG signing?